# Spring pubsub Filter Messages for subscriber

Tags: spring-integration, google-cloud-pubsub

I try to implement a request async Response Pattern using pubsub. I'm doing this by using spring Integration. I've defined a topic and two subscriptions on both ends (Event Sender for async response and Event consumer for request). But If consumer sends Response it is send to Sender and Consumer. But consumer Event ist empty. All good so far. My Question is how can i defined a Filter for messages in springs pubsub Integration. It is a Feature in Google pubsub.

Comment: Any chances to see some code from you to better understand what is going on?

Comment: Sorry, quickstart can be created next workday. So far i dont have any Code for Filtering available. Only the Event Sending is currently implemented.

Comment: Right, but what you have so far to determine the spot where you'd like to add that filtering. Probably simple Spring Integration `Filter` would be enough for you in the flow: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#filter

Comment: That Looks promising. I will give It a try and come Back with a result.

Comment: Did the answer help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use Spring Filters to let you take action whether the message should be dropped or carried forward to a message channel. You can see more [information](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2021/06/spring-integration-filters.html).

You can see these examples.

```
@Filter(inputChannel = "inputChannel", outputChannel = "secretChannel")
boolean filter(Message<?> message) {
    String msg = message.getPayload().toString();
    return msg.contains("secret");
}
```

You can see these examples on how to implement the filtering in spring. You can see more [examples](https://programmer.group/three-main-ways-of-implementing-message-filtering-in-spring-cloud-stream.html).

```
package com.zj.node.contentcenter.controller.content;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Source;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
 
/**
 * Producer
 *
 * @author 01
 * @date 2019-08-03
 **/
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TestProducerController {
    private final Source source;
    @GetMapping("/stream-send-msg")
    public String streamSendMsg(String flagHeader) {
        source.output().send(
                MessageBuilder.withPayload("Message Body")
                        // Setting the header for filtering messages
                        .setHeader("flag-header", flagHeader)
                        .build()
        );
        return "send message success!";
    }
}
```